# Mouse stuttering and video lag issue

Tags: linux, lag, cursor

I just installed LXLE on my old laptop. The system seems to be running great but it keeps randomly lagging. It does it for no apparent reason. It comes and it goes. It will happen when there is no load on the cpu. I have plenty of ram and a new Samsung SSD installed.

I've tried a few things but I can't figure it out. Anyone have any tips or thoughts? Thanks for your time.

Comment: **Important:** @mrwislr's answer and its (now deleted) comments were the subject of a private dispute between mrwislr and me. While this dispute has been resolved to *mrwislr*'s satisfaction, please do not delete the question or answer because doing so could restart the dispute.

Answer (score 1):

As the developer of LXLE, I can say this is caused by the system performing security updates in the background. You can verify this using the `top` command in a terminal.

Let the system finish the updates and the stuttering should clear up.